# Retrieve data via link parameter in react

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-router-dom

I have a list of user on a page , what i want to achieve is render user detail when i click on the link with his id. for that i have tried to send the id and retrieve the data with a new request like this :

My routes :

```
<Route path='/coupeurs' element={<Coupeurs />} />
<Route path='/coupeurs/add' element={<AddCoupeur />} />
<Route path='/coupeurs/:id' element={<Coupeur />} />
```

My list :

```
<ul>
    {coupeurs.map(coupeur => (
      <li key={coupeur.id}>
        {coupeur.nom} {coupeur.prenom}
        <div className='coupeur-actions'>
          <Link to={`/coupeurs/${coupeur.id}`}>Voir</Link>
          <Link to={`/coupeurs/${coupeur.id}/edit`}>Editer</Link>
        </div>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
```

the place where i want display details :

```
  export default function Coupeur(props) {
  console.log(props);
  let { id } = useParams();
  const [coupeur, setCoupeur] = useState(getCoupeurInfoById(id));
  console.log(coupeur);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Identifiant :  {id}</h3>
      <h3>Nom :  {coupeur.nom}</h3>
      <h3>Prenom :  {coupeur.prenom}</h3>
      <h3>Statut :  {coupeur.statut}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My getCoupeurInfoById function :

```
export async function getCoupeurInfoById(id) {
  const docRef = doc(db, "coupeurs", id);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
    return docSnap.data();
  } else {
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
}
```

i get my page without the info , but when i console log my variable i can see the result !
Can you help me found the right way to do that kind of things ? thank you

Comment: Can you include all relevant code you are working with? What is this `getCoupeurInfoById` function doing? Is it doing anything asynchronously?

Comment: Yes sorry , but you have right it work asynchronously !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getCoupeurInfoById` is an `async` function it implicitly returns a `Promise` object and subsequently (*quickly*) resolves and mutates the `coupeur` state variable. When you log it you see the resolved value.

The `useState` hook expects a synchronous function that returns the initial state value.

Use a `useEffect` hook to handle the side-effect of fetching/computing the `coupeur` value.

Example:

```
export default function Coupeur(props) {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [coupeur, setCoupeur] = useState(); // <-- initially undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCoupeur = async () => {
      try {
        const coupeur = await getCoupeurInfoById(id);
        setCoupeur(coupeur);
      } catch(error) {
        // handle any rejections/errors/etc
      }
    };

    getCoupeur(); // <-- fetch/compute coupeur value
  }, [id]);

  if (!coupeur) return null; // or loading indicator/etc

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Identifiant :  {id}</h3>
      <h3>Nom :  {coupeur.nom}</h3>
      <h3>Prenom :  {coupeur.prenom}</h3>
      <h3>Statut :  {coupeur.statut}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}
```